# How to find places along the route using google map api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-directions-api

If you are getting the route using google.maps.DirectionsService() (say from e.g: Reims to Paris). Now, how can we get all places (say if searching hotels, restaurants or gas stations) which can be found on/along this route (later which will be added to map as markers with their information along with route).

After googling a lot, found nothing useful. Google have short info about such query as http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165392&topic=1650221&ctx=topic

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update**
Have found some more similar questions but not satisfying question or have answer:

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858384/how-to-find-location-along-a-route-with-google-maps)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382510/how-to-find-the-location-between-two-places)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753674/how-do-i-show-places-in-google-maps-api-v3-and-google-places-api-between-two-p)

Comment: For an example, I want to accomplish something like ([example link](http://www.meetways.com/Halfway-point-between-Paris-France-and-Reims-Frace-poi-Hotel-ahw-0.html)) on  [this site](http://www.meetways.com).

Comment: I found another [site](https://roadtrippers.com) which have implemented this feature

Comment: Perhaps [the answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283826/how-to-to-get-places-e-g-gas-stations-along-route-between-origin-and-destinati) may help.

Comment: Why don't you search nearby, for some points of the route? Try this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: This is an older question so I am not sure if you still need a solution but take a look at: [RoadLi](http://road.li/) built by [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072341/doug) using Google Maps API3 (along with other things)...I would contact him and ask about it.